# Can i add new column in DataFrame with Interpolation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, interpolation

this is my current DataFrame:

```
    Df:
    DATA
    4.15
    4.02
    3.70
    3.51
    3.17
    2.95
    2.86
    NaN
    NaN
```

i  alredy know that 4.15(first value) is 100%, 2.86(last value) is 30% and 2.5 is 0%. firstly, i want to interpolate first column the NaN(second last)value based on last NaN is 2.5(this is alredy predfined). after this i want to create second column and interpolate based on first coumn and available these three percentage value.

is it possible?

i have tried this code but it is not giving expected results:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'DATA':range(df.DATA.min(), df.DATA.max()+1)}).merge(df, on='DATA', how='left')
    df.Voltage = df.Voltage.interpolate()
```

Expected output:

```
    Df:
    DATA    %
    4.15   100%
    4.02   89%
    3.70   75%   
    3.51   70%
    3.17   50%
    2.95   35%
    2.86   30%
    2.74   15%
    2.5    0%
```

Comment: Which kind of interpolation do you want to use?

Comment: @mozway linear Interpolation

Comment: Then the filled value should be 2.68, not 2.74, can you also explain the logic of the %?

Comment: basically, when the battery's DATA is 4.15, means full 100% and 2.5 means 0%.   i know the three percentage value for 4.15(100%), 2.5(0%) and 2.86(30%).  rest of percentage is for interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is unclear, my understanding is that you want to compute a rank, but the provided output is unclear, please details the computations.

What I would do:

```
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'DATA'] = 2.5

df['DATA'] = df['DATA'].interpolate()

# compute rank
s = df['DATA'].rank(pct=True)

# rescale to 0-1 and convert to %
df['%'] = ((s-s.min())/(1-s.min())).mul(100)
```

output:

```
   DATA      %
0  4.15  100.0
1  4.02   87.5
2  3.70   75.0
3  3.51   62.5
4  3.17   50.0
5  2.95   37.5
6  2.86   25.0
7  2.68   12.5
8  2.50    0.0
```